# Sharepoint 2010 Visual WebPart and LinqDataSource

Tags: visual-web-part

How do I use Linq DataSource in a SharePoint 2010 Visual Web-part. When I type `<asp:LinqDataSource` there are nothing in the Visual Studio auto-complete. When I run the code I would get this error Unknown server tag 'asp:Linq DataSource'

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, refer to this link 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010programming/thread/0c7275b8-58fd-456a-9c06-5bdd5a7bccdb

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.