# LINQ DataSource DataContext: Could not load type

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, linq

I made a very simple webpart with a grid view and and a LINQ to SQL data context object to surface some employee information for a phone list.  I was able to databind the grid view directly to LINQ query objects, which worked well.  However, this approach leaves you without sorting capability.

Moving forward, I wanted to use an ASP.NET LinqDataSource instead of an object datasource.  I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18188/sharepoint-2010-visual-webpart-and-linqdatasource) answer when I couldn't figure out how to actually get a LinqDatasource object to correctly render in the markup.

What the answer (and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edd6daa6-c1b2-4fc7-9c36-a54af5cf579d/use-linqdatasource-in-sharepoint-visual-web-parts)) fails to mention is that the LinqDataSource can't talk to any of your DataContext objects out of the box.

I found [this fellow](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2aab520-76d7-4ea9-9916-d99c1717f5d4/linq-datasource-datacontext-type-unable-to-load?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) who is having a similar issue.  The dude answering assumes he's talking about the SharePoint DataContext object and then a MSMVP marks his answer as correct because...  banana, I guess.

Either way, here's what I have.

## Markup

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="aspweb" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="LinqTest2.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl" %>

<asp:GridView ID="derp" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="herp" 
EnableModelValidation="True">
</asp:GridView>

<aspweb:LinqDataSource ID="herp" runat="server" ContextTypeName="TydbDataContext" />
```

## Exception

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'TydbDataContext'.]
>   [InvalidOperationException: Could not find the type specified in the ContextTypeName property of LinqDataSource 'herp'.]

I've verified that my LINQ to SQL DataContext type is correct in the markup and that the DataContext can be instantiated in the codebehind.

I don't care if the answer is 'not possible, go find another solution'.